# Remove string object from array of string

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

How to remove particular object from array of string. Here is my array of string

```
[
Top cities,
==================================,
Bangalore,
Mumbai,
Delhi,
----------------------------------------,
Kerla
]
```

We want to remove those three objects which is not related to cities.

I have tried below code but its not removing all objects. Its removing only "Top cities"

```
if let idx = self.arrayValues.firstIndex(where: { ($0 as! String) .contains("Top") || ($0 as! String) .contains("======")||($0 as! String) .contains("------") }) {
                    self.arrayValues.remove(at: idx)
                }
```

Decodable class

```
struct Service : Decodable {
    var name: String
    var id: String
}

struct Location : Decodable {

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case locationList
    }
    var locationList : [String]?
}

extension Location {
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        locationList = try values.decodeIfPresent([String].self, forKey: .locationList)
    }
}
```

we have two type of response, You can understand by Decodable class

Comment: Why do you need to cast element to the `String`? Isn't `self.arrayValues: [String]`?

Comment: array will change based on response type it might be array of string or array of json

Comment: Well, then your code will crash if it's not the array of `String`.

Comment: `arrayValues` is an array of `Any` ? cast it to `[String]` or post your json response

Comment: we are handling like below 
 if isType == 1{
            filterArrayValues = searchText.isEmpty ? arrayValues : arrayValues.filter {
                ($0 as! String).localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText)
            }
        }else{
            filterArrayValues = searchText.isEmpty ? arrayValues : arrayValues.filter {
                ($0 as! Service).name.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText)
            }
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`firstIndex` gets the index of the first item only while you need all indices that satisfy the filtering , you can easily use `removeAll`

```
var arrayValues = ["1","2"]
self.arrayValues.removeAll(where: { $0.contains("Top") || $0.contains("======")|| $0.contains("------") })
```

Comment: Thanks its works, i have tried with  wrong method firstIndex and you can understand my response by Decodable class

Answer (score 1):

This amounts to the same as the accepted answer, but, in case you want to adopt the  functional programming approach, you might want to do as follows:

```
let arrayValues = ["1","Top cities","2","======"]
let newArrayValues = arrayValues.filter { !$0.contains("Top") && !$0.contains("======") && !$0.contains("------") }
```

You might also want to separate each filtering condition as follows:

```
let newArrayValues = arrayValues
    .filter { !$0.contains("Top") }
    .filter { !$0.contains("======") }
    .filter { !$0.contains("------") }
```